# Angular js with jquery multi select plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, multi-select

I am using a jQuery plugin which converts a normal select dropdown into a fancy multi select dropdown. Here's the plugin url:
http://wenzhixin.net.cn/p/multiple-select/

Now, the problem which i am facing now is that, I am using angular js to bind the dropdown values. And, I used the angular js directives as

```
app.directive('ccMultipleSelect', function () {
    var directive = {
        link: link,
        restrict: 'A'
    };
    return directive;

    function link(scope, element, attrs) {
        element.multipleSelect({ selectAll: false });
    }
});
```

And in my html view code is as below:

```
<select data-ng-options="c.key as c.value for c in vm.units" 
    multiple="multiple" data-cc-multiple-select>
</select>
```

But, issue is that, when the directive event is called i.e. where the multipleSelect plugin is called, by that time the angular js didn't done its binding and thus the fancy dropdown contains no elements. One quick solution which I thought is to use the setTimeout function to call the plugin after 500ms , but that's not an ideal solution. There must be some other way through which we can watch the dropdown elements and refresh the elements further.

Comment: Could you put this in a fiddle or something?

Answer (score 0):

Option 1 : Have you tried timeout without any delay. I had similar issue with other  : jquery plugin which did not load dynamic data.

Option 2 : redraw multiselect  $('select').multipleSelect();